# Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule'

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am run aspnet_regiis.exe, still I am getting same error:

> Could not load type ‘System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule’ from
>   assembly ‘System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089′. Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code. Exception Details:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   ‘System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule’ from assembly
>   ‘System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089′.

Comment: Can you provide info about .net / asp.net and iis versions?

Answer (score 21):

If you are running Windows 8, this method will not work. Microsoft will not let you to run this command, telling you this:

> > This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.

The reasons for this are on this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736284 .

The solution that worked for me is posted on this link, on the answer by Neha: [System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374639/system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-error/15523900#15523900)

> > Everywhere the problem to this solution was mentioned as re-registering aspNet by using aspnet_regiis.exe. But this did not work for me.
> >
> > Though this is a valid solution (as explained beautifully here)
> >
> > but it did not work with Windows 8.
> >
> > For Windows 8 you need to Windows features and enable everything under ".Net Framework 3.5" and ".Net Framework 4.5 Advanced Services".
> >
> > Thanks Neha

Comment: This resolved my issue on windows server 2012.  Note I had to carefully ensure ALL 3.5 and 4.5 items were checked...look close cause some of that stuff is easy to miss.  Stranger yet, cause my WCF project is compiled for 4.0

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error after upgrading the IIS server to .NET 4.5.1 (previously .NET 4.0 was installed).
In my case, running **`aspnet_regiis`** with the parameter **`-iru`** fixed the problem, ie.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -iru
```

**Note:** on a **64bit system** you should use

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -iru
```

---

**Notes:**

- .NET 4.0 and higher (e.g. 4.5.1) all installs into v.4.0.30319, this has changed compared to earlier versions (you will not find a v4.5 folder). To get the installed .NET framework versions, see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826686/1016343)** answer.
- The cause of this error is described **[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015129)**, If you want to check manually, I cite the following from this article:

> This issue occurs because the **Applicationhost.config** file for Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) has the following section defined, and **this section is incompatible with the .NET Framework 4.0:**
>
> `<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />`

This section should be defined as follows (notice the `preCondition`):

```
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, 
System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```

**Note**: You can find the **`Applicationhost.config`** file in the following location: `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`

Comment: Encountered the same error after installing .NET Framework **4.5.2** on Windows Server 2008 R2. Running **aspnet_regiis.exe /iru** resolved it for me. And note that as stated in the Microsoft article that you reference that on a 64-bit computer one should do the registration from the 64-bit folder **%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319**.

Comment: I had to change the Applicationhost.config in order to get it work on Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the ASP.NET 4.0 is not properly registered with IIS. Could you please try re-registering asp.net with IIS ? You could try for both 2.0 and 4.0 just to make sure it is done for all the .NET versions.

Use the following commands for both version of asp.net to register asp.net with IIS

aspnet_regiis -i

This is located in both .NET framework version folders.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
and
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Answer (score 2):

Get to the applicationhost.config file in the following directory:
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config

The following section will be defined:

```
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

The above definition is incompatible with the .NET framework 4.0, you can get this issue resolved by replacing the above section by the following:

```
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late, hope it will help someone ....This is a known issue with IIS 8.0

> The solution is to delete the 3.x module and handler from IIS manager.
>   You could delete them at the application or site level if you want to
>   keep them in applicationHost.config. But I wanted to delete them from
>   applicationHost.config. do the following steps:
>
> In IIS manager, click the machine name node. In “Features View”,
>   double-click “Modules”. Find “ServiceModel” and remove it. Image 1 for
>   Solve IIS 8 Error: Could not load type
>   ‘System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule’
>
> Go back to the machine name node’s “Features View”, double-click
>   “Handler Mappings”. Find “svc-Integrated” and remove it. Image 2 for
>   Solve IIS 8 Error: Could not load type
>   ‘System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule’

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, run the following command line:

- aspnet_regiis.exe /iru The Aspnet_regiis.exe file can be found in one
  of the following locations:
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 (on a 64-bit computer)

Comment: Please describe how running that exe will address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, run the following command line:

1. Close the Application
2. in the project file(Web Application) change the virtual directory
3. Now OPEN the Project file

It will work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 2012, the following worked :

For a reason I don't know the default application pool was set up to use 4.0 :

[Application Pool Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0pMt.png)

but it was not correctly reflected in c:\windows\system32\inetesrv\config\applicationhost.config :

```
<add name="DefaultAppPool" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" />
```

I had to set it back to 2.0 and then to 4.0 again, and then the config file was fine and the error disapeared :

```
<add name="DefaultAppPool" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
```