# Could not load type '%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll'.

Tags: web-services, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

New Windows server 2012 R2 installation, added ASP.Net and .Net 3.5
Getting following error when trying to browse web service file svc:

> Could not load type '%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check pool application framework. Do you have this framework version `v4.0.30319`

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt as administrator

Navigate to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation`
and execute the command:

```
ServiceModelReg.exe /i
```

Navigate to `c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`
and execute the command:

```
aspnet_regiis -iru
```

Some roles and features are required on the server

- enable server role "Internet Information Services", all underlaying services will be included
- enable feature "HTTP Activation", this both under .NET framework 3.5 and .NET framework 4.5

In IIS make sure there is a "handler mappings" configured for the "*.svc" files

Comment: aspnet_regiis doesn't work on newer versions of Windows (8, 10, Server 2012R2). Instead see this answer for information on which Windows Features should be enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198981/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule

Answer (score 0):

That error message turned out to be a bit of a red herring when I encountered it. I simply didn't have a HEAD route setup in WebApiConfig and was getting hundreds of HEAD requests per day. So, if you've verified that you have all the [necessary Windows Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198981/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule) installed, then next check that you have default routes setup for each [HTTP request method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).