# Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel

Tags: iis, service, svc

I'm running my Web Project in IIS.

It is a 4.0 Framework APP.

I have a Service.svc and I get this error when I run my Application.

> "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from
>   assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

I tried this --> aspnet_regiis.exe -iru which I found in a lot of forums and it didn't solve my problem.

Does anyone know another method ?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Try with

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
```

When multiple versions of the .NET Framework are executing side-by-side on a single computer, the ASP.NET ISAPI version mapped to an ASP.NET application determines which version of the common language runtime (CLR) is used for the application.

Above command will Installs the version of ASP.NET that is associated with Aspnet_regiis.exe and only registers ASP.NET in IIS.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2015129/error-message-after-you-install-the--net-framework-4-0-could-not-load

Comment: also we can user CMD : by entering address , cd\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 and then install it by : aspnet_regiis.exe -iru command , next  it would be better to restart ISS by iisreset

Comment: This is still proving helpful today.  I would have hoped by now MS would have fixed this.  In my case, we already have a running IIS application using ASP.net 4.0 framework.  While not exactly sure what the customer did other than to upgrade to 4.5.1 and a bunch of other updates, it became necessary to re-run this command, something our support engineers didn't think of because they haven't had to do it for some time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this, however, did not work for me. but enabling everything under '.Net Framework 3.5' and '.Net Framework 4.5' in windows features (as mentioned in below answers) did the trick.

Comment: I have a windows server 2008 x64 R2 and it worked fine but after one month , 
I got this error,I found this post and run this command on my server and it fixed my issue.
I never install or update anything on my server, now the question is why did it happen?, is it normal or it's a hack type or something like that?

Comment: In my case, everything was fine until I was led by MS to install .NET Framework 3.5.1 on my Windows 7 machine in order to fix an unrelated error occurring every time I tried to use the context menu (right-clicking) in the Event Viewer. As soon as I installed this earlier .NET release, it caused the stated error on this thread, "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule'..." in the Event Viewer whenever I tried to debug a web app on my box that uses the .NET 4.0 application pool (I'm a developer). Well, running "aspnet_regiis.exe -iru" as suggested above fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: I get this message:  Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

Comment: This is still proving helpful today.

Comment: It's worked for me only if I run `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru` for `v4.0.XXXXX` **AND** `v2.0.XXXXX` versions!

Answer (score 53):

I have Windows 8 installed on my machine, and the aspnet_regiis.exe tool did not worked for me either.

The solution that worked for me is posted on this link, on the answer by Neha: [System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374639/system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-error/15523900#15523900)

> Everywhere the problem to this solution was mentioned as re-registering aspNet by using aspnet_regiis.exe. But this did not work for me.
>
> Though this is a valid solution (as explained beautifully here)
>
> but it did not work with Windows 8.
>
> For Windows 8 you need to Windows features and enable everything under ".Net Framework 3.5" and ".Net Framework 4.5 Advanced Services".
>
> Thanks Neha

Comment: This advice is also necessary for Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks for passing this along. Worked great to fix this on Win 8.1

Comment: You don't need to enable everything, just Http Activation!

Comment: What Marius said, just Http Activation under .NET 3.5 Features

Comment: You & Neha saved my remaining hairs

Answer (score 40):

Hello Thanks for the question; 
To resolve: "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

In Windows Features check all for .NET 4 Advanced Services & .NET 3.5

[image]

Just like Nicolas Gago I tried aspnet_regiis.exe -iru but it didn't work. After the features were on then it yellow screen error was gone. Thanks;

Comment: This worked for me in Windows Server 2012 R2 - thanks!

Comment: I only had to enable "Http Activation" as I hosted the services in IIS. It worked for me, thanks.

Comment: This fixes the problem in Windows 8.1

Comment: Worked for me in windows 10.

Comment: Worked for me in Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 12):

You can install these features on windows server 2012 with powershell using the following commands:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name  NET-Framework-Features -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-WindowsFeature -Name  NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45 -IncludeAllSubFeature
```

You can get a list of features with the following command:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok, finally got it.

Change this line in `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\Config\ApplicationHost.config`

```
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

To

```
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```

If this is not enough

Add this following line to the Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Changing the ApplicationHost.config worked for me with Windows Server 2016. All the other answers did not help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From the Server Manager's Features node, you can also remove some of the sub-items under the .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features that are installed by the activation of some of the other roles.

For instance, removed the WCF Activation Features as follows and our websites came back:

- [x] .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features
- - [x] .NET Framework 3.5.1
  - [ ] WCF Activation

    - [ ] HTTP Activation
    - [ ] Non-HTTP Activation

Note: this did not require a restart for us.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows server 2012. Go to ISS -> Modules -> Remove the ServiceModel3-0.

Answer (score 1):

Details

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179(v=nav.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179%28v=nav.71%29.aspx)

"This error can occur when there are multiple versions of the .NET Framework on the computer that is running IIS..."

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after I accidentally published one website into the directory of another website. The two websites had different versions of .net. What fixed it for me was changing the application pool. To do that, in the IIS manager:

click the website => Advanced Settings... (on the right) => click to the right of Application Pool => a button with "..." should appear => select ".NET v4.5 Classic"

If that application pool doesn't work, try some of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I am late, hope it will help someone ....This is a known issue with IIS 8.0

> The solution is to delete the 3.x module and handler from IIS manager. You could delete them at the application or site level if you want to keep them in applicationHost.config. But I wanted to delete them from applicationHost.config. do the following steps:
>
> In IIS manager, click the machine name node.
>   In “Features View”, double-click “Modules”.
>   Find “ServiceModel” and remove it.
>   Image 1 for Solve IIS 8 Error: Could not load type ‘System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule’
>
> Go back to the machine name node’s “Features View”, double-click “Handler Mappings”.
>   Find “svc-Integrated” and remove it.
>   Image 2 for Solve IIS 8 Error: Could not load type ‘System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule’

Answer (score 0):

We are using a web service along side a web site and when we publish the web site it returns same this error.  We found out that by going into IIS and removing the ServiceModel from Modules and the svc-Integrated from the Handler Mappings the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You might changed the IIS features settings.The easy steps to resolve by open command prompt  with run as administrator(For Windows Server 2008) and run the command
**C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru**
this will set up ASP.Net 4.0 ,Then Reset the IIS by the command
**iisreset**

References:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213392249-ASP-website-shows-error-Could-not-load-type-System-ServiceModel-Activation-HttpModule-from-assembly

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the `Applicationhost.config` file for Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) has some tags that are not compatible with the .NET Framework 4.0.

Based on your environment, you have 4 workarounds to solve this issue:

- Updating Applicationhost.config.
- Perform ASP.NET IIS Registration.
- Turn on the Named Pipe Activation feature.
- Remove ServiceModel 3.0 from IIS

> Check the detailed steps for each woraround at **[Solving Could not load type system.servicemodel.activation.httpmodule from assembly System.ServiceModel](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel/)**

Answer (score -2):

delete the module which is identified in .Net error message ,  1 down vote

In Windows server 2012. Go to ISS -> Modules -> Remove the ServiceModel3-0. (without number worked for me)

Answer (score -2):

start-> Run--> `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru`