# Hosting WCF service in an existing ASP.Net , Deployment Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, deployment

I am trying to use an already existing ASP.net web application to host a WCF service, so I tried the following steps,

1- In Visual Studio 2010, I created web application through the **Web** > **ASP.net Web Application** template, named **WebApp**.

2- Added new WCF Service through **Add** > **New Item ...** > **WCF Service** , named **MyServ**.

3- Modified the `DoWork()` method in MyServ.svc as follows,

From

```
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
```

To

```
        public string DoWork()
        {
             return "hello";
        }
```

and consequently I modified IMyServ.cs to match the new signature.

4- When I run the application on development server and visit `http://localhost:1399/MyServ.svc`  , the service runs fine.

5- So I create a publish for this application, to prepare it to be hosted on the IIS.

6- In the IIS, I create a new website named **WebAppSite** and is given the port 111, so now when I visit `http://localhost:111/` , I am directed for the published WebApp site default page, which is fine and shows that the aspx part of the application is working fine on the IIS.

7- So I try to visit `http://localhost:111/MyServ.svc` to check if the service is successfully deployed, but I get this message,

**HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.**

Any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to register the .svc mime type in your IIS

run "\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe -i"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the IIS seems to understand service files now, but unfortunately I am receiving this exception now. Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: problem solved at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688930/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-from-assembly-s

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://hpatel.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/problem-hosting-wcf-service-in-iis-7-5-or-svc-mime-type-and-script-mapping-issue-while-wcf-services-access/) is a full guide, please apply all steps:

1. Add “.svc” extension and MIME Type as “application/octet-stream” to IIS Mime Type in Features View.
2. Register Asp.net by running aspnet_regiis.exe -i command from VS 2010 command prompt (Run as admin).
3. Right click cmd, run as admin, go to “C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation” folder and run : ServiceModelReg.exe -i

If you did some changes in your IIS, you may need to go to handler mappings, right click on the static file and select "Revert to Parent".