# Can't add a service reference on home computer

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on a project with a few colleagues and I'm creating my own service. Whenever I try to add a service reference to the project it fails. Here is the service I wish to add after I've double clicked it in the services list:

[image: Adding]

... and here is the rather unhelpful error I get when I open the URL in Chrome.

[image: Error]

It's a completely fresh pull and adding services worked on my university computer. I've tried disabling my firewall as I read on the MSDN help network but to no avail. I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: Improve you question by Adding more detail such as Add you Service Configuration Details etc............

Comment: The message is not that unhelpful. It's telling you that it couldn't find the service type you've specified in either the markup of the service file (.svc) or in the config file.  What is the namespace and name of your service?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register .net 4.5 with IIS, [try to register it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13749209/2558060)

check below post for similar issue but note that below question is related to .net 4.0

[Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688930/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-from-assembly-s)