# Call to WCF Service works local but not on server 404

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have a simple WCF service which recieves some data from jquery.

The service Works fine on localhost, but hosted in IIS 7.5 i returns a 404 error

I have read all the other questions here but cant find the solution.

My jquery looks like :

```
function SaveBannerData(bannerArray) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://xxx.xxx.xx/StatService.svc/SaveBannerStat",
    data: "{\"pageBanners\":" + JSON.stringify(bannerArray) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {},
    error: function (xhr) { bannerFailed(xhr)}
});
```

}

And my WCF like :

```
namespace Comito.Portal.DataService
{
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class StatService
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

    public void DoWork(List<BannerStat> pageBanners)
    {
        List<Comito.LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.Advertice.AdverticeStat> insertData = new List<LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.Advertice.AdverticeStat>();
        foreach (BannerStat item in pageBanners)
        {
            Comito.LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.Advertice.AdverticeStat adverticeStat = new LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.Advertice.AdverticeStat();
            adverticeStat.AdStatType = LokalPortalen.Domain.Enums.AdStatType.View;

            adverticeStat.Advertice = item.dataAd > 0 ? new Comito.LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.Advertice.Ad { ID = item.dataAd } : null;
            adverticeStat.AdZone = item.dataZone > 0 ? new Comito.LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.Advertice.AdZone { ID = item.dataZone } : null;
            adverticeStat.StatDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            insertData.Add(adverticeStat);                
        }
        Comito.LokalPortalen.DataStore.Repositories.Advertice.AdverticeStat.UpdateAllNoSession(insertData);
        return;
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class BannerStat
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int dataType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int dataZone { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int dataAd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is `SaveBannerStat`  method?

Comment: Sorry - the DoWork should be SaveBannerStat

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to call WCF service on cross domain then you must have to allow cross domain access in your WCF service else you get error. here, i am sharing reference URL to allow WCF service for cross domain

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/X8QN260412-Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-Service-using-Jquery.html

Additionally I am share 1 more blog url which is help you to understand jQuery AJAX and JSONP call. This will more help to understand exact difference between AJAX and JSONP method

http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery

Comment: Could the problem be that i have Windows Server 2008 with .net Framework 3.5.1 Features and not 4.5 ?

Comment: Thought it was related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784908/wcf-net-4-5-on-windows-server-2008-r2?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: compare your local machine IIS configuration and server IIS configuration