# How to check if WCF 4.5 is installed on Windows 2008 server machine using c#

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, powershell, installation

I need to write a program to check if WCF 4.5 is installed and activated on 2008 machine or not. If not then I need to activate WCF 4.5 using C#.

How to detect WCF 4.5 on windows 2008 machine using C#?

Comment: search google first..

Comment: Riad, I already did that. Let me  know if you are referring to any post/blog/article which I missed. The issue is even the Server Manager on win 2k8 machine does not display the details about WCF 4.5.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784908/wcf-net-4-5-on-windows-server-2008-r2